# Limit at infinity of $\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}=0$

But why is \begin{align} \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^n x^{-1}} =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{x^n}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x^n} \end{align} indeterminate?

Suppose I have the absolute value, is the limit still indeterminate? \begin{align} \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg\lvert \frac{1}{x^{n-1}}\Bigg\rvert &=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg\lvert \frac{1}{x^n x^{-1}}\Bigg\rvert \\ &=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg\lvert \frac{1}{\frac{x^n}{x}}\Bigg\rvert =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg\lvert \frac{x}{x^n}\Bigg\rvert \end{align}

Comment: Why do you think $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ must be zero?

Answer (score 1):

Is your question about $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac x {x^n}$ being zero, or about $\displaystyle\frac \infty \infty$ being zero? The first one is true (for $n > 1$), the other one is indeterminate. Because for instance $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac {x^{2n}} {x^n} = +\infty$ is also of the form $\displaystyle\frac \infty \infty$.

The point is that $\displaystyle\frac \infty \infty$ is just a notation for a type of limits and not an equality with the previous term.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Well, the thing is, *indeterminate form* does not apply to limits, but rather to their combination. If in your formula $\frac x {x^n}$ you replace both terms by their limits, you obtain $\frac \infty \infty$ which is indeterminate. However, the limit is still (and always will be) $0$ (for $n> 1$).

Answer (score 1):

The description "indeterminate" is ***not*** a description of the limit, or a description of the function you're taking the limit of — it is a description of *the specific formula you've written*.

When the formula is a determinate form, such as $1 / \infty$, you're guaranteed that the limit must equal the value you get by computing the determinate form: in this case, $1/\infty = 0$. Any other determinate form for the same function will also evaluate to zero.

When you write the function in an indeterminate form, all that says is that you can't determine the limit simply by evaluating the limit form. It doesn't preclude you from finding the limit in some other fashion.

---

As an aside, with care, sometimes you can still glean information from indeterminate forms; e.g. while $1/0$ is<sup>*</sup> an indeterminate form, you're guaranteed that of the limit exists, it is either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Similarly, while $\sin(\infty)$ is indeterminate, the limit (if it exists) will lie somewhere in the interval $[-1, 1]$.

(And even though $\sin(\infty)$ is indeterminate, if you're careful with the details you can see that $\sin(\infty) / \infty$ is determinate, despite the intermediate calculation being indeterminate!)

<sub>*: I'm specifically considering extended real-valued limits here. This form is determinate for projective real-valued limits</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[*By definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), if a limit is of the type $\frac\infty\infty$, it is indeterminate. (I am not asserting that this is the only case in which a limit is indeterminate.)

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^n}=0$ requires $n \gt 0$

Let $m=n-1$

Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^m}=0$ when $m \gt 0$

which is the same as saying $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}=0$ when $n \gt 1$

But $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$  is $1$ when $n=1$ and is $\infty$ when $n \lt 1$, so in this sense is indeterminate without knowing more about $n$.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: @JDoeDoe since $x \to \infty$, we only need to consider positive $x$, in which case $x^n$ and $\dfrac1{x^n}$ and $\dfrac1{x^{n-1}}$ and $\dfrac{x}{x^n}$ are all positive for all real values of $n$, so taking absolute values of these makes no difference to the limit

Answer (score 0):

For $n>0$, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$$ is **not inderteminate**, it is just $1$ ($n=1$) or $0$ ($n>1$) by elementary computation.

By rewriting as

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{x^{n}}$$ you are making it an indeterminate form, artificially. The latter is easily evaluated by... simplifying and reverting to the initial expression.

---

By the same reasoning, you would say that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}1$$ is indeterminate because $$\lim_{x\to\infty}1=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac xx =\frac{\infty}{\infty}!$$

Answer (score -1):

Indeterminate simply means "we don't know". It can be any number or even infinity. For example

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ax+1}{x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty} a+\frac{1}{x}=a$$

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{ax^2+1}{x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty} ax+\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$$

Note that all these limite are indeterminate limites of the forms $\frac{+\infty}{+\infty}$.